# Jasper Report module for openerp 7

Tags: odoo

I was able to do report in openerp6.1 using jasper report module.It worked fine.But now i want to do this in openerp7.I couldn't found any fully functional jasper report module.http://pragtech.co.in/7.0/jasper_reports.zip -from this site i downloaded module.Due to install it gives error.Can anyone help me??Thanks in advance.

Comment: Jasper MOdule for OpenERP from Pargtech is not so Producative,rather go for Jaser Moduel form SYLEAM Team. they are mataining it activly : https://launchpad.net/openerp-jasperserver

Answer (score 0):

Latterly I also got stacked when I try to setup Pentaho report for OpenERP v6.1 (actually and v7.0 also). And then I found this link..

http://www.schenkels.nl/2013/04/creating-a-pentaho-reporting-server-ubuntu-12-04-openerp/

Every step described in this link works well but this part:

> Add the underlying xml between the `<tomcat-users> </tomcat-users>` of
>   the file you opened

When I try to preview report from the Pentaho Report Designer, it works smoothly. But when I try to click print button in my OpenERP, I always get an error "Connection refused". Then I changed the password to `admin` and it works well now ( but not sure this will works for you too). So the xml syntax are going to be like below:

```
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status"/>
```

...just if you get that error too.
After that, everything goes well.

Good luck!!